# Dictionary data structure + fast complexity methods

Tags: java, algorithm, dictionary, data-structures, big-o

I'm trying to build from scratch, a data structure that would be able to hold a vast dictionary (of words/characters).

The "words" can be made out of arbitrarily large number of characters.

The dictionary would need standard methods such as search, insert, delete.

I need the methods to have time complexity that is **better** than `O(log(n))`, so between `O(log(n))` to `O(1)`, e.g `log(log(n))`

where **n = dictionary size** (number of elements)

I've looked into various tree structures, like for example b-tree which has `log(n)` methods (not fast enough) as well as trie which seemed most appropriate for the dictionary, but due to the fact that the words can be arbitrarily large it seemed liked it's complexity would not be faster than `log(n)`.

If you could please provide any explanation

Comment: What do you denote by `n` here?

Comment: Dictionary size usually.

Comment: A trie has big memory requirements but the access time is of course faster than `O(log n)`. If I recall well, the access time depends on the length of the word, not of the count of the words in the structure. It also depends on exactly what implementation of the trie you use.

Comment: Might aswell turn that into an answer, he didn't say anything about mem constraints.

Comment: Is your dictionary only going to be a list of words, or do you expect to store some information about each word as well? If the former, [DAFSA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_acyclic_finite_state_automaton) might be the best choice for you

Comment: yep no memory requirements, but if I have huge word, heaps of characters, would the trie still be the fastest approach then?

Comment: Is there some reason why hash tables are not suitable for your requirements ?

Comment: Without any specification on the length of the words, this question cannot be answered. The minimum achievable complexity could be much larger than Log(n).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A trie has significant memory requirements but the access time is **usually** faster than `O(log n)`.

If I recall well, the access time depends on the length of the word, not of the count of the words in the structure.

The efficiency and memory consumption also depend on exactly what implementation of the trie you chose to use. There are some pretty efficient implementations out there.

For more information on Tries see:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie

http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/52trie/

http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/52trie/TrieST.java.html

https://www.topcoder.com/community/data-science/data-science-tutorials/using-tries/

Comment: Maybe you can provide some links to the mentioned implementation strategies or even provide them here (schematics)? :)

Comment: "the access time is of course faster than `O(log n)`": no, the access time is `O(m)` for words of length `m` and you can very well have `m>log(n)`.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yes, of course but I assumed normally one would have the opposite inequality. So yes, that's what I meant here. Of course it somewhat depends on the base of the logarithm too. Anyone can do the math given e.g. 100,000 words in the dictionary and given e.g. a natural logarithm.

Comment: The OP explicitly states long strings. For a million entries, Log(n) is just 20. In my understanding, a string of 20 characters isn't long at all.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Well, I thought that "arbitrarily large <> long strings"... Anyway, why don't you post an answer but keep hunting down each word I put in mine? We're on the same page, anyone can do the basic math, OK? If you have a better answer - why not write it.

Comment: @YvesDaost the data structures which claim O(log n) performance actually do O(log n) comparisons taking O(m) time each.  It is not physically possible for any algorithm to take less than O(m) here, so O(m) is asymptotically optimal.

Comment: @peter.petrov: I use to not answer questions with insufficient specifications like this one. Usually, a trie is not asymptotically faster than Log(n) as the keys must be long enough take at least n distinct values, which requires at least Log(n) bits.

Comment: Thanks for the links, but I meant you should put them in your answer for the history books, since comments are destined for the bin eventually

Answer (score 1):

If your question is how to achieve as few string comparisons as possible, then a hash table is probably a very good answer, as it requires close to `O(1)` *string comparisons*. Note that hashing the key value takes time proportional to the string length, as can be the time for string comparison.

But this is nothing new. Can we do better for long strings ? To be more precise, we will assume the string length to be bounded by `M`. We will also assume that the length of every string is known (for long strings, this can make a difference).

First notice that the search time is bounded below by the string length, and is `Ω(M)` in the worst case: comparing two strings can require to compare all characters as the strings can differ only in the last character comparisons. On the other hand, in the best case, the comparison can conclude immediately, either because the lengths are different or because the strings differ in the first characters compared.

Now you can reason as follows: consider the whole set of strings in the dictionary and find the position of the first character on which they differ. Based on the value of this character, you will decompose in a number of subsets. And you can continue this decomposition recursively until you get singletons.

For example,

```
able  
about  
above  
accept  
accident  
accompany
```

is organized as

```
*bl*
*bou*
*bov*
*c*e**
*c*i****
*c*o*****
```

where an asterisk stands for a character which just ignored, and the remaining characters are used for discrimination.

As you can see, in this particular example two or three character comparisons are enough to recognize any word in the dictionary.

This representation can be described as a finite state automaton such that in every state you know which character to check next and what are the possible outcomes, leading to the next states. It has a `K`-ary tree  structure (where `K` is the size of the alphabet).

For an efficient implementation, every state can be represented by the position of the decision character and an *array* of links to the next states. Actually, this is a trie structure, with path compression. (As said by @peter.petrov, there are many variants of the trie structure.)

How do we use it ? There are two situations:

1) the search string is known to be in the dictionary: then a simple traversal of the tree is guaranteed to find it. It will do so after a number of character comparisons equal to the depth of the corresponding leaf in the tree `O(D)`, where `D` is this depth. This can be a very significant saving.

2) the search string may not be in the dictionary: during traversal of the tree you can observe an early rejection; otherwise, in the end you find a single potential match. Then you can't avoid performing an exhaustive comparison, `O(1)` in the best case, `O(M)` in the worst. (On average `O(M)` for random strings, but probably better for real-world distributions.) But you will compare against a single string, never more.

In addition to that device, if your distribution of key lengths is sparse, it may be useful to maintain a hash table of the key lengths, so that immediate rejection of the search string can occur.

As final remarks, notice that this solution has a cost not directly a function of `N`, and that it is likely that time sublinear in `M` could be achieved by suitable heuristics taking advantage of the particular distribution of the strings.

Comment: Insertion and deletion in a trie or a hash table are quite possible. Anyway this answer does not address the issue of dynamic *storage* of the strings in case of insertions and deletions, which is a harder question.